# Conditionally dumping an attribute using pyyaml/ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, python-dataclasses, ruamel.yaml

I have a Python class something like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object, YAML

yaml = YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class DataObject:
    normal_attr: str
    normal_attr_2: str
    conditional_attr: str
```

I want to then be able to conditionally dump `conditional_attr` using `ruamel.yaml` (which is based on PyYaml) based on some condition. Ideally it would work something like this:

```py
data = DataObject()

if verbose_output:
    yaml.dump(data, stream)
else:
    yaml.dump(data, stream, exclude=['conditional_attr'])
```

Of course this doesn't actually work, but is there some way to implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be a good idea to implement excluding of certain mapping keys as an option to the dump method.

And apart from that `ruamel.yaml` already has a
[documented method to do special dumps](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html) which you can use to filter out
any attribute, e.g. for those where the name starts with `conditional_`:

```
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object, YAML

yaml = YAML()

verbose_output = False

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class DataObject:
    normal_attr: str
    normal_attr_2: str
    conditional_attr: str

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        d = {}
        for k in node.__annotations__:
            if not verbose_output and k.startswith('conditional_attr'):
                continue
            d[k] = node.__getattribute__(k)
        return representer.represent_mapping('!DataObject', d)

data = DataObject(normal_attr='a', normal_attr_2='b', conditional_attr='c')

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives:

```
!DataObject
normal_attr: a
normal_attr_2: b
```

Comment: I think it would be ideal to specify the fields when at the point of serialization. This is what Marshmallow does: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#filtering-output

Comment: Anyway, this answer is a start, but `verbose_output` is a global variable here which doesn't actually solve my issue because you can't reasonably create a re-usable module that allows the user to configure the verbosity.

Comment: `verbose_output` is a global variable in your code, that is why I continued it usage here. If you have a single serialization routine adding arguments might be ok, but  ruamel.yaml  (and PyYAML)  have multiple serializations that would all need updating with every new parameter someone comes up with. IMO much more effeicient to do this in an object oriented way that every serializer can use.

Comment: If I needed something like this I wouldn't have used a global variable like you did, but add an attribute `yaml.verbose_dataclass_output = False`. And make an alternative decorator for `yaml_object` that still take a YAML instance as parameter but adds the to_yaml classmethod (that checks for the `verbose_data_class` attribute) to every class it decorates.